# MVVM how to get notify event for a nested class object

Tags: c#, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

Hi I know that there a posts about this topic, but I could not solve my problems with them.

I want to understand and learn a simple way to get a ViewModelBase that I can subcribe to in my View so that a UI Refresh is forced.

I have written an windows console example. The structure is Class Customer(string Name, MyAddress Address) where MyAddress is a Class(string StreetName). In Main I have a list of customers. Now I want to get a message every time there is a change in the list or in the property of the customer including a change of the streetname.
I cant get that to work. If I change the name of the customer it works but not for the 'nest' address. If I change StreetName I dont get a notify Event. I don't know how to subcribe to the ViewModelBase for all the customers in the list.
The Console Progam can be copy/paste in VisulaStudio and runs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CS_MVVM_NotifyFromNestedClass
{
    class Program
    {
        public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

            protected void SetValue<T>(ref T backingFiled, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingFiled, value)) return;
                backingFiled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            }
        }

        public class Customer : ViewModelBase
        {
            private string _name;
            public string Name
            {
                get => _name;
                set { SetValue(ref _name, value); }
            }
            public MyAddress Address { get; set; }
            public Customer(string name, MyAddress address)
            {
                Name = name;
                Address = address;
            }
        }
        public class MyAddress : ViewModelBase
        {
            private string _street;
            public string Street
            {
                get => _street;
                set { SetValue(ref _street, value); }
            }

            public MyAddress(string street)
            {
                Street = street;
            }
        }

        public static BindingList<Customer> MyCustomers = new BindingList<Customer>
            {
                new Customer("John", new MyAddress("JoStreet")),
                new Customer("Susi", new MyAddress("SeaStreet")),
            };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //BindingList Event 
            MyCustomers.ListChanged += OnBindingListChanged;

            // 1) Change Name  <-- THIS FIRES THE 'OnBindingListChanged' EVENT
            MyCustomers[0].Name = "Rick";
            // 2) Change Street  <-- THIS DOESN'T FIRE A CHANGE-EVENT
            MyCustomers[0].Address.Street = "Rockyroad";
            //I dont know how to hook up the 'property change event' from ViewModelBase for all obj. of MyCustomer-List
            //MyCustomers[0].Address.PropertyChanged += OnSingleObjPropChanged;  // <--doesn't work

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static void OnBindingListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1) BindingList was changed");
            foreach (var c in MyCustomers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{c.Name}  {c.Address.Street}");
            }
        }
        private static void OnSingleObjPropChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Never reached --> how to 'hook'
            Console.WriteLine("2) Property of List Item was changed");
            foreach (var c in MyCustomers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{c.Name}  {c.Address.Street}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First Edit:  inner BindingList in the CustomerClass plus the ViewModelBase @Karoshee

I did leave the MyAdresse thing out to simplify. I added a BindingList 'MyTelNrs' to my CustomerClass and subcribt to the ListChanged Event. I didn't change the ViewModelBase from the execpted answere. I do get a notification in my UI, but I don't know if I'am doing it in a save/right way. Just to let the following readers know ... (maybe someone that is better then me answeres, if the below way is 'okay')

```
    public class Customer: ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set => SetValue(ref _name, value);
        }

        public BindingList<string> MyTelNrs = new();

        private void OnLstChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyTelNrs));
        }

        public Customer(string name, BindingList<string> myTelNrs)
        {
            Name = name;
            MyTelNrs = myTelNrs;

            MyTelNrs.ListChanged += OnLstChanged;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you rename `ViewModelBase` to `ObservableObject` or similar.

Comment: Okay that would not be a problem, but how does that help here?

Comment: It's a _comment_ **not** an _answer_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all need to make `Address` property a notify property:

```
            public MyAddress Address
            {
                get => _address;
                set
                {
                    SetValue(ref _address, value);
                }
            }
```

Than you need to add some additional logic into `ViewModelBase`, something like this:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// All child property values and names, that subscribed to PropertyChanged
    /// </summary>
    protected Dictionary<ViewModelBase, string> nestedProperties 
        = new Dictionary<ViewModelBase, string>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void SetValue<T>(ref T backingFiled, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingFiled, value)) return;
        if (backingFiled is ViewModelBase viewModel)
        {   // if old value is ViewModel, than we assume that it was subscribed,
            // so - unsubscribe it
            viewModel.PropertyChanged -= ChildViewModelChanged;
            nestedProperties.Remove(viewModel);
        }
        if (value is ViewModelBase valueViewModel)
        {
            // if new value is ViewModel, than we must subscribe it on PropertyChanged 
            // and add it into subscribe dictionary
            valueViewModel.PropertyChanged += ChildViewModelChanged;
            nestedProperties.Add(valueViewModel, propertyName);
        }
        backingFiled = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    private void ChildViewModelChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this is child property name,
        // need to get parent property name from dictionary
        string propertyName = e.PropertyName;
        if (sender is ViewModelBase viewModel)
        {
            propertyName = nestedProperties[viewModel];
        }
        // Rise parent PropertyChanged with parent property name
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {   // need to make sure that we unsubscibed
        foreach (ViewModelBase viewModel in nestedProperties.Keys)
        {
            viewModel.PropertyChanged -= ChildViewModelChanged;
            viewModel.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

As I know this does not contradict the MVVM, the only issue with subscribing/unsubscribing child property changed.

**Updated:**

I added few changes and comments in code below.

The key thing here, that you need to subscribe to PropertyChanged of child properties that inherited from ViewModelBase.

But subscribing is a half way throught: you need to make sure that you unsubscribe it, when objects does not need anymore, so it's has to be stored in `nestedProperties`.

Also we need to replace child property name from `ChildViewModelChanged` with parent property name to rise PropertyChange event on parent object. For that goal I saved property name with property value than subscribed on `ChildViewModelChanged`, this is why I use Dictionary type in `nestedProperties`

Also important thing to unsubscribe all ProperyChanged, when object no longer needed. I added IDisposable interface and Dispose method to do that thing. Dispose method also needs to be rised (with `using` or manualy), in your case perhaps will be better to make own `BindingList` with `IDisposable`, that rise Dispose on all items.

Comment: THANK you. It works ( for the first quick tries :) ... I must say that I do can estemate what the code is doing, but I am not able to understand it line by line :( Did you come up with this by yourself, or can you post a link to maybe more info on this approche? Anyway much thanks for your time. Hopefully I do get it to work in a Blazor App. Its been a  few rough days/nights

Comment: Welcome, I updated answer with some explanations, hope this will help.

Comment: Hi, would it be to much to ask if you could add one last piece? I wanted to also use a nested List inside the Customer class. As an example I think of  TelephoneNrs from Customer (List<string>). What type of List should I use (ObservableList/BindingList) and how can I get Notify Event from inside those lists (how to change ViewModelBase for the case that  List<int> TelephoneNr is a property of Class Customer).  I should have asked that right at the beginning but I did forget about it.

Comment: `BindingList` should work fine for inner collection, just need to make sure that you subscribed to `ListChanged`, and rise `PropertyChanged` from it. About simple types such as `int` or `string` inside list, it's can be a little bit tricky. You can make you own generic class `Notifier<T>` for example, where T is your type, inside this class you have notified property of that type.

Comment: Okay I did make a edit to my original Post with my 'solution' for a inner List. I do get notified in the UI with this approache. I just don't know if that is save :) I don't understand the 'dispose' stuff I have to read up on that.

Comment: The purpose of `IDisposable` in our case to help `GarbageCollector` do it's job: releasing memory. In two words: unnecessary objects that have subscribed events live longer that suppose to be, because GC believes that object is still using, so it can lead to memory leak in worst case. If you want to go deeper, read about how GarbageCollector work, specialy with subscibed events. Honestly: i've added `IDisposable` on reflex, just in case. Also I have strong feeleng that something can changed in GC and I should refresh my awareness of this too ^^